# Most efficient way to push multiple forms submissions at once(Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework, offline-caching

My clients will be using the app in areas that may potentially have bad to no internet connection and I am wondering what would be the best way to possibly store form submission offline locally on the device. Once they reach an area of good signal strength to either systematically or manually push the form data in some sort of a queue to the APIs.

I have a simple example that I am currently using, but it is for one submission only. If the API response fails, the users connection is offline, or the promise breaks, the user is given an option in an alert to store the form data locally and can continue and later manually sync in the settings to attempt to push the form data once again to the API.

I'm not sure if this is a good practice, but I was wanting to know what options I have and what would be the best practice for performance of the app and reliability of form submissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way out to keep the information locally to handle the failed or offline scenario and i.e. browser stroge -

### 1. Cookie

If you want to keep the data for with expiry time, you can opt for cookie. However you should avoid this if you have pretty heavy data.

### 2. Local Storage

Its pretty good choice if you have big data and you want to clear the local data as soon as user closes the browser.

### 3. Session Storage

This would be good choice if you want to retain big data and after browser is closed.

Comment: So I would possibly want to use local storage for the fact that the app may be closed.